# How to consume HornetMQ message in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to integrate HornetMQ Consumer in Springboot application. I have seen different example but all of them are pointing ActiveMQ implementation which make me little bit confuse. I have written a standard HornetQ Consumer in java. Here is a code:

```
public class HornetQClient {

private String JMS_QUEUE_NAME;
private String MESSAGE_PROPERTY_NAME;

private ClientSessionFactory sf = null;
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TCPClient.class);

public HornetQClient(String hostName, String hostPort, String queueName, String propertyName) {
    try {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("host", hostName);
        map.put("port", hostPort);
        this.JMS_QUEUE_NAME = queueName;
        this.MESSAGE_PROPERTY_NAME = propertyName;

        ServerLocator serverLocator = HornetQClient.createServerLocatorWithoutHA(new TransportConfiguration(NettyConnectorFactory.class.getName(), map));
        sf = serverLocator.createSessionFactory();
        startReadMessages();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void startReadMessages() {
    ClientSession session = null;
    try {
        if (sf != null) {
            session = sf.createSession(true, true);

            while (true) {
                ClientConsumer messageConsumer = session.createConsumer(JMS_QUEUE_NAME);
                session.start();

                ClientMessage messageReceived = messageConsumer.receive(1000);
                if (messageReceived != null && messageReceived.getStringProperty(MESSAGE_PROPERTY_NAME) != null) {
                    System.out.println("Received JMS TextMessage:" + messageReceived.getStringProperty(MESSAGE_PROPERTY_NAME));
                    messageReceived.acknowledge();
                } else
                    System.out.println("no message available");
                messageConsumer.close();
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error while adding message by producer.", e);
    } finally {
        try {
            session.close();
        } catch (HornetQException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error while closing producer session,", e);
        }
    }
}
```

This one is working fine but is there any standard way to write Message Consumer in spring boot application or should i directly create a bean of this client and use in Springboot application

--------------- hornetq-jms.xml---------

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hornetq /schema/hornetq-jms.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:hornetq">
    <!--the connection factory used by the example -->
    <connection-factory name="ConnectionFactory">
        <connectors>
            <connector-ref connector-name="netty-connector" />
        </connectors>
        <entries>
            <entry name="ConnectionFactory" />
        </entries>
        <consumer-window-size>0</consumer-window-size>
        <connection-ttl>-1</connection-ttl>
    </connection-factory>
    <queue name="trackerRec">
        <entry name="trackerRec" />
    </queue>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps use Spring JMS and `JmsTemplate` for this. The default set up for Spring boot is using an ActiveMQ connection factory, but if you exchange this for a HornetQConnetionFactory, you should be good to go:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class JmsConfig {
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        final Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("host", "127.0.0.1");
        properties.put("port", "5445");
        final org.hornetq.api.core.TransportConfiguration configuration =
            new org.hornetq.api.core.TransportConfiguration("org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory", properties);
        return new org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQJMSConnectionFactory(false, configuration);
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> myFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

I added the fully qualified class names for clearity.

Then, in some bean, you can just do this to consume a message:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "some.queue", containerFactory = "myFactory")
public void receiveMessage(@Header("some.header") final String something) {
    System.out.println("Received <" + something + ">");
}
```

Disclaimer: I have not actually tried this in practice, it is based on my experience with Spring and ActiveMQ, as well as these sources: https://dzone.com/articles/connecting-spring https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/

You might have to do some digging to get this to work the way you want, but I think this approach is a bit more "high-level" than the one you are going for.

Comment: Thanks. I have tired this and configuration seem to be ok as i not get any error while running application but somehow unable to get any message.

Comment: Not sure about how HornetQ works, but do you see any indications of your application listening on the queue in the HornetQ gui?

Comment: Yes it is listening because when i shutdown hornetQ server while client connected, in client side i can see a warning messages related to that it disconnected from server etc..

Comment: So the messages are just queuing up on the queue?

Comment: Yes. @JmsListener which you suggested seems to be not correct as it not reading any message from queue. However if i add incorrect queue name this complain in start of application that queue not found. This is very strange that everything seems to be properly configured but still not message received in client side.

Comment: It might be that HornetQ requires the setup of a default destination. Check my first link to see how it was done.

Comment: what do you mean by "setup of default destination" ? Do you mean configure a queue in hornetq-jsm.xml like this:  <queue name="DemoQueue">
  <entry name="/queue/DemoQueue"/>
 </queue> 
I tried this way as well but no luck